# Running chatterbot with Microsoft Bot Emulator - Connection Refused Error

Tags: python, azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework, chatterbot

I've been struggling with understanding how the Microsoft Bot Emulator works in terms of the ports it listens on.

Problem - I am trying to build a toy bot that will run on the emulator, using Chatterbot, a python package. Chatterbot has input and out adapters for Microsoft (using Directline). As per their tutorial, I created a toy example that looks something like this:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
data_path = 'XXXX'

# Uncomment the following lines to enable verbose logging
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = ChatBot('toybot',
              storage_adapter = 'chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
              input_adapter = 'chatterbot.input.Microsoft',
              output_adapter = 'chatterbot.output.Microsoft',
              directline_host = "http://localhost:3979",
              logic_adapters=[
        'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation',
        'chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter'
    ],
              #database = data_path + 'database.sqlite3'
             )

while True:
    try:
        bot_input = bot.get_response(None)
    except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

My questions:

1. Will this code snippet work on the emulator? Or, does this require a bot hosted on Azure?

Right now, if i run this code and start the emulator, I either encounter a 'connection refused error' or the emulator says the endpoint isn't found.

2. In the line `directline_host = "http://localhost:3979"`, is the port number supposed to be the desired endpoint for the emulator? Or, should it be the port on which the emulator is listening? (a 5-digit number that changes every time the emulator starts)

Comment: What endpoint are you using in the emulator?  generally, endpoints look like  `http://localhost:3979/api/messages`

Comment: Yes, that's the endpoint I used. The default in mine shows as 3978. Do I need to use the same address in the code above? That doesn't appear to work.

Comment: no, you can use whatever port you want just as long as your project is running on the same port as the emulator is expecting.  In your case 3978.

Comment: I think there are some misunderstanding about Bot Framework Emulator with you, it's just an interface to help communicating between you and your bot server for debugging and troubleshooting, please refer to two offical documents [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-quickstart) & [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-emulator) to know more.

Comment: And there is a MS blog introduce how to use DirectLine in Python to build a bot, see it from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamiedalton/2017/07/06/using-the-bot-framework-from-python-with-the-direct-line-api/).

Comment: Apologies, thanks @PeterPan, that helped.